Установить плагин winrm в vagrant последней версии
Установил Vagrant последней версии: sudo dpkg -i vagrant_2.4.1-1_amd64.deb. Файл скачал с официального сайта.
Ставлю плагин winrm через прокси (блокировки со стороны hashicorp):
https_proxy=localhost:34289 vagrant plugin install winrm

Проверяю: vagrant plugin list, плагинов нет: No plugins installed..
ОС: Ubuntu 20.04.6
Помогите решить эту проблему - плагин ставится, но в списке его нет.
Пробовал также:

бинарный файл vagrant отсюда - та же проблема
официальный репо (apt) - старая версия vagrant 2.2.6, мне не подходит
запускал strace - ничего полезного не нашел
снес через apt purge vagrant, rm -rf ~/.vagrant.d/, rm -rf /opt/vagrant, удалил Ruby apt remove ruby, затем ставил vagrant заново - та же проблема

